# sql query getting groups of two or more similar rows

Tags: sql

I have a table with this schema:

[image]

The context is people who are traveling the same day and almost same hour.

What i need to obtain from it is:
**Groups of people who have a similar date (2 +/- hours max of diference) same place and same type and they have to appear two or more times together with that constrains.**

In the image above John and Steve should appear in the results since they share all the requisites for the query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This problem seems to need the ability to group on each and every entry and then find the rows that are within the range of that single entry. But then again if you use an arbitrary median time this gets even more tricky. What needs to be done is maybe more explanation of the exact logical requirements for each "group".

Comment: Which RDBMS (Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, etc) is this? Date functions/operators vary between RDBMS, so this will affect the answer.

Comment: Is for a table made with access but can be migrated to sql server 2008. Studying the case with several colleagues we found the necesity for data mining. As @LaurenceBurke said we need to compared every entry and apply the grouping to that. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @euther, I have post an answer for your query. Please, check if this helps with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all, migrate table to SQLServer 2008 as you say.
Then, this query can help to you for groups of 2 people:

```
select t1.pesonId as Person1, t2.personId as Person2
from
   yourTable as t1
   inner join
   yourTable as t2
     on 
       t2.PersonId > t1.PersonId and --to avoid t1,t2 and t2,t1
       t2.Place = t1.Place and
       t2.Type = t1.type and
       t2.date between dateadd( hh, -2, t1.date ) and dateadd( hh, +2, t1.date)
group by
   t1.pesonId, t2.personId
having count(*) > 1   --more than one time as you say
```

Then, this query can help to you for groups of 3 people:

```
select t1.pesonId as Person1, t2.personId as Person2,, t3.personId as Person3
from
   yourTable as t1
   inner join
   yourTable as t2
     on 
       t2.PersonId > t1.PersonId and 
       t2.Place = t1.Place and
       t2.Type = t1.type and
       t2.date between dateadd( hh, -2, t1.date ) and dateadd( hh, +2, t1.date)
   inner join
   yourTable as t3
     on 
       t3.PersonId > t2.PersonId and 
       t3.Place = t1.Place and
       t3.Type = t1.type and
       t3.date between dateadd( hh, -2, t1.date ) and dateadd( hh, +2, t1.date)
group by
   t1.pesonId, t2.personId, t3.personId
having count(*) > 1   --more than one time as you say
```

I have [tested first query in data taking Post as your table](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61222), here de results:

```
Person1 Person2     
------- ------- --- 
22656   23354   584 
22656   29407   237 
22656   23283   230 
22656   69083   189 
22656   57695   178 
157882  203907  177 
26428   131527  175 
20862   131527  163 
22656   34397   159 
22656   65358   150 

(10 row(s) affected)
```

For more elaborate analysis I suggest to you use SSAS or move to a datamining tool like [knime](http://tech.knime.org/getting-started).

Comment: Consider records at 00:00, 01:00 and 04:00. These are all +/- 2 hours from 2am, but would not be returned by this query.

Comment: Why not? @Dems, `00:00 between 02:00-2h and 02:00+2h` = `00:00 between 00:00 and 04:00` = true!

Comment: Another shortcut... since they want another person, instead of doing personA != personB (which would give you results for PersonA, PersonB and PersonB, PersonA), change it to PersonA < PersonB so it will only return the common instance between them ONCE..

Comment: @DRapp, just doed. I come to change it and I see your comment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dems, his query is good.  Even if start time was Feb 1 at 12:03 AM, subtract 2 hours would be Jan 31, 10:03pm.. by the DateTime column being compared, it WOULD qualify.  DaniHP is not doing an ordinal HOUR() of a date/time value.